# Scala-Requests : How to send x-www-urlencoded form data?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how would it be possible to post form Data using scala-requests library: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala

Is it natively supported or I have to try some hack?

Here's what I tried with but seems like its failing:

```
requests.post(
      url = endpoint,
      headers = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization" -> s"Bearer $bearerToken"
      ),
      data = json
    )
```

where `json` is a JSON string: `{"name":"test","age":12,"class":"3esasfc"}` which is supposed to be sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Comment: This content type is `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example

Comment: Or the content (data) must be `name=test&age=12...`. It seems the library supports passing a `Map` to data, you might try that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data by using `params` instead of `data` in request.post method.

Rest all worked fine.